# Entity Framework Returning NULL in circular collection

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an odd issue I have never seen before. Entity framework is returning a NULL object in a navigational property collection.  I am accessing it in a circular manner though when I view it.  You can see the screenshot below on the collection and the NULL object.  I also gave the path below.  Any clue why this is happening?

I caught this because AutoMapper didnt like it.

```
`"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\n\nMapping types:\r\nDivision -> DivisionModel\r\nTournaments.Data.Entities.Division -> Tournaments.Models.Divisions.DivisionModel\n\nDestination path:\nList`1[0].Event.Divisions.Divisions1[1]\n\nSource value:\nTournaments.Data.Entities.Division"`
```

Entity Path

```
DivisionBracket -> Division - Event -> List<Divisions> (has NULL and original Division)
```

**Division.cs**

```
[Table("Division", Schema = "")]
    public class Division : BaseEntity
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EventId")]
        public Event Event { get; set; }
```

**Event.cs**

```
[Table("Event", Schema = "")]
    public class Event : BaseEntity
    {
        [InverseProperty("Event")]
        public virtual ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
```

**Mapping**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Division>() .HasRequired(a => a.Event) .WithMany() .HasForeignKey(u => u.EventId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

[image]

Comment: you need to post your entity code, can you post your code this time and not a picture aswell

Comment: please add model definitions, to understand better the situation, and probably to show the problem

Comment: Are you using Automapper in your code? Please add your model classes.

Comment: If you look at the code there is quite a bit of classes. Which ones would you like to see specifically?  The screenshot should help to determine what you would like to see.

Comment: I am using automapper, but not where this issues occurs.

Comment: 1)Would you add Division and Event definitions?, 2)Also I would like to see how are you querying, as it's wrapped into the method GetMany. And 3) are you trying to see content in Event.Divisions property? because I don't see any of this in your include expression

Comment: I am not trying to see Event.Divisions in this method, but outside of it I do.  As you can see in the debugging, the Event.Divisions is populated since Entity Framework picks it up because its referenced the othe way.

Comment: there could be a number of reasons. have you marked that property as virtual?
could you post your mapping code ?

Comment: Added more information.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Division has mising mapping configuration. Probably you need to add relation mapping on DivisionMap.cs (1 to N mapping)

**For ex**

**It cause this error**

this.HasOptional(a => a.Occupation).**WithMany()**.HasForeignKey(c => c.OccupationId);

**Correct way**

this.HasOptional(a => a.Occupation).**WithMany(x=>x.Employee)**.HasForeignKey(c => c.OccupationId);

Comment: So my mapping is this. 

`modelBuilder.Entity<Division>()
                        .HasRequired(a => a.Event)
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(u => u.EventId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Comment: Sorry i see ypu comment now. Your problem is lack of mapping configuration. You need to add foreign key relation in  modelBuilder.Entity<Division>() .HasRequired(a => a.Event) .WithMany(a=>a.Evemt) .HasForeignKey(u => u.EventId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);